# How to truncate data in a dict so that the resulting JSON isn't longer than n bytes?

Tags: python, unicode, json, micro-optimization

I have a python 2.7 dict such as `{u"eat": u"糖果", u"drink": u"café"}`, and I need to transfer it using JSON.  The JSON string must be regular ASCII and it must be less than 256 chars.

So far, I have coded this:

```
import json

def payload_to_json(payload, max_size = 256):
    while True:
        json_string = json.dumps(payload, separators = (',', ':'))
        if len(json_string) <= max_size:
            return json_string
        max_length, found_key = 0, None
        for key, value in payload.iteritems():
            length = len(value)
            if length > max_length:
                max_length = length
                found_key = key
        if max_length == 0:
            return "" # just in case max_size is really low
        payload[found_key] = payload[found_key][:-1] # remove one char
```

It works as expected:

```
>>> payload = {u"eat": u"糖果", u"drink": u"café"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload)
{"drink":"caf\u00e9","eat":"\u7cd6\u679c"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=41)
{"drink":"caf","eat":"\u7cd6\u679c"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=35)
{"drink":"ca","eat":"\u7cd6\u679c"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=34)
{"drink":"c","eat":"\u7cd6\u679c"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=30)
{"drink":"c","eat":"\u7cd6"}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=21)
{"drink":"","eat":""}
>>> print payload_to_json(payload, max_size=20)
```

It seems to me that there should be a way to optimize this! I'm really stripping one character at a time, it feels so wrong.

My question is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777987/how-to-truncate-data-in-a-hash-so-that-the-resulting-json-isnt-longer-than-n-by), except I use python 2.7, and the json encoder produces pretty long JSON strings whenever the source strings contain non-ASCII unicode chars.

Plus I'm pretty sure this will break with UTF-16 surrogate pairs...

Comment: Are you talking about "optimize" in terms of performance, or readability?

Comment: Well, I was talking about performance.  Is my code unreadable?

Comment: No, my point was that if you try to make it faster, it will probably become less readable, and that's probably not worth it. (As a case in point, I think your code is much more readable than mine, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make this faster (which you shouldn't be, unless you know this is a hotspot in your program with a real performance cost), you can first guess the number of characters to strip, and then deal with leftovers.

First, if you need to strip 52 characters, and there are 10 keys, you need to strip 6 chars each from 2 keys, and 5 each from the other 8, right? Except, of course, that you may be trying to strip 6 chars from something that's only 4 chars long, which means you'll end up still 2 chars over the limit. But you can keep track of those leftovers and deal with them after you're done. It's unlikely that there will be enough leftovers to make another pass through the "fast" version worth doing, so you might as well just use the "slow" version.

```
def payload_to_json(payload, max_size = 256):
    json_string = json.dumps(payload, separators = (',', ':'))
    chars_to_strip = len(json_string) - max_size
    if chars_to_strip <= 0:
        return json_string
    key_count = len(payload)
    chars_per_key, extras = divmod(chars_to_strip, key_count)
    leftover = 0
    for i, key in enumerate(payload):
        to_strip = chars_per_key + (i < extras)
        orig_len = len(payload[key])
        if orig_len < to_strip:
            payload[key] = ''
            leftover += to_strip - orig_len
        else:
            payload[key] = payload[key][:-to_strip]
    if leftover:
        return slow_payload_to_json(payload, max_size)
    else:
        return json.dumps(payload, separators = (',', ':'))
```

I'm not sure this actually *will* speed things up in your use cases. For very small objects and max sizes, I wouldn't be surprised if it actually slows things down. But for huge objects way over the max size, it would probably help a lot.

Comment: I like your comment about the fact that I should not be trying to optimize this code.  You're probably right.  It's just that it feels soooo wrong!  ;-)

Comment: I'm amazed that you came up with this so quickly, but I'd like to trim the longest strings first, and not modify the short strings unless I have to.

Comment: OK, that's doable too. Let me think for a second.

Comment: In English: First sort by length (`sorted(payload.items(), key=lambda item: -len(item[1]))`). Then you can easily calculate how much you'll save by truncating to each length, in O(N) amortized total time. So, keep decreasing the length until `savings >= chars_to_strip`. Then, `underflow = savings - chars_to_strip`. Truncate the last `underflow` values to maxlen+1, and everything else to maxlen, in a single pass. Then convert the sorted `list` back to a `dict`.

Comment: Or… instead of truncating `item[1]`, truncate `payload[item[0]]` to save the cost of converting back. Anyway, needless to say, this is also going to be more complicated and less readable than your original code, so consider whether it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

How about computing the **serialized size of each entry**.

Then choose as many elements such that you have the desired length?

Either way, this sounds like a really bad idea overall.

Comment: He's trying to truncate each value, not strip out key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep as many keys as possible, and avoid shortening the short strings unless I really have to.  What sounds like a really bad idea? Trying to optimize this code? Or the idea of shortening strings to fit inside 256 chars?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the strategy in the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777987/how-to-truncate-data-in-a-hash-so-that-the-resulting-json-isnt-longer-than-n-by):
you measure the first generated json, then you strip from the values the right amount of chars in the preferred order.

otherwise you could guess the number of chars json uses by counting: for each mapped variable these chars `"":"",` plus the overall `{}`, minus a comma. (unless you don't have a more complicated nested list, obviously)

the unicode functionality shouldn't be a problem as long as you use `u''` notation (not sure, but shouldn't be difficult to check)

Comment: I tried to use the strategy from the other post, but it wasn't great because of non-ASCII chars.  For example, those two chinese chars in my example are encoded into 12 ASCII chars in the JSON string.  So if I apply the suggested strategy, I should remove 12 chars from one string, and then there's just nothing left at all.

Comment: If you want to go that way, you'd need two steps: First `encode('unicode_escape')` everything in the `payload`, then minimize the escaped payload. But you probably want to do this anyway—otherwise, you're paying for the cost of escaping each time you re-check the results. (Although I'd guess that's much cheaper than the `json.dumps`, it's still not free.)

Comment: seems to me that the simpler approach is counting the chars that `json.dumps()` add... given that the dict you are using is mono-dimensional!
so you don't have to deal with unicode, though it may seem 'hackish'...

Comment: @caesarsol: Doing it that way, you'd have no way of knowing how many of those chars are being added by the UTF-8-ifying, and how many by the JSON-ifying. (Besides, he clearly wants unicode_escape rather than UTF-8 in the end result.)

Comment: @abarnert: by exclusion i know how many chars are added by the JSON-ifying: `len('{}')+len(payload)*len('"":"",')-len(',')`. then something like this could tell you the same for the UTF8-ifying: `len(''.join([k.encode('unicode_escape')+v.encode('unicode_escape') for k,v in payload.iteritems()]))`. isn't this more convenient than cycling through the entire dict, pulling one char and re-JSON-ifying at every step?

Comment: ( just noticed that `é` is given as `\\xe9` by `encode('unicode_escape')`, and as `\\u00e9` by `json.dumps()`. is it for you too? there should be another usable function.)